# Differentiating nested function of infinite series with respect to one element

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, summation

I have the expression $$E^g = \frac{\sigma^2 P}{1-\gamma}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_i^2}{(\lambda_i p + \kappa)^2}$$

Where $\kappa = \frac{m_n(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_M)}{m_{n-1}(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_M)}, \gamma = \sum_i \frac{p\lambda_i^2}{(\kappa + p\lambda_i)^2}$. I seek to find a closed form for $\frac{d(E^g)}{d\lambda_i}$. I am struggling to find a command to 1) express that $\gamma, \kappa$ are functions of *all* (infinitely many) $\lambda_i$ in $E^g$, and also to 2) use `SymmetricPolynomial` with first argument `n` being a symbol rather than number to write $\kappa$ in Mathematica. I am somewhat new to Mathematica, so any help is much appreciated. Many thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please show what you have tried in Mathematica, in copy passable code. This makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: If $\kappa$ is invariant by permutation of the $\lambda_i$ then maybe you could look at only the derivative with respect to $\lambda_{1}$ and generalize from there. In that case, you could maybe use $\kappa(\lambda_{1},s)$   where s is a single variable. Formally, the structure would be the same if it was $\kappa(\lambda_{1},s)$, $\kappa(\lambda_{1},s1,s2)$ or an infinite sequence of variables.

Comment: Consider copy-pasting the Mathematica code as one could just copy-paste that rather than type the expression in a notebook.

Comment: Also $E^g$ can be re-written in terms of $\gamma$ rather than the sum, so one could first obtain the formal derivative with $E^g[\gamma,\alpha=\sigma^2P/p]$ and obtain the derivative in terms of $\gamma$ then substitute the expression for the derivative of $\gamma$. The derivative of $\gamma$ will have derivatives of $\kappa$ and you might want to try to write that back in terms of $\gamma$ if possible. I do not know what the $m_n$ notation is in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Up to copy and paste errors a finite version would look like

```
Eg[M_, n_] := ((σ^2*P)/(1 - Sum[(p*λ[i]^2)/
(m[n][λ /@ Range[M]]/  m[n - 1][λ/@ Range[M]]), {i, 1, M}]))*
 Sum[λ[k]^2/(λ[i]*p + m[n][λ /@ Range[M]]/
 m[n -1][λ /@ Range[M]])^2, {s, 1, n}]
```

The derivative with respect to [Lambda][1]

```
D[Eg[3, 4], λ[1]] /. {x_[i_Integer] :> 
   ToExpression[ StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {x, i}]}


 
    -((8 P σ2 λ[k]2 (-((m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}] m3({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
    m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]2)+m4({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]/m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]))/
    ((1-(p λ12 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-(p λ22m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
    m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-(p λ32 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
    m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]) (m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]/
m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]+p λ[i])3))-
(4 P σ2 λ[k]2 (-((2 p λ1 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])-
(p λ12 m3({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-(p λ22 m3({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-
(p λ32 m3({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]+(p λ12 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}] m4({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]2+(p λ22 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}] m4({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]2+(p λ32 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}] m4({1,0,0})[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]2))/((1-(p λ1^2 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-(p λ2^2 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]-(p λ3^2 m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])/
m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}])2 (m4[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]/m3[{λ1,λ2,λ3}]+p λ[i])2)
```

Please no comments about errors. This is a demonstration of readable definitions only, that work at least without input errors.